# SQL WHERE clause like JOIN query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, where-clause, sql-server-express

I have the below procedure which fetches the booking count and total price for each month.

Now I need to pass additional parameter `@HasObservation` as an additional parameter. The logic to filter is not just a normal field filter. It has to be filtered by joining with other table PatientXObservation. If this table has entries for value 1,2,4 then only filter those bookings.

**@HasObservation=1 mean, FETCH RECORDS SATISFIES THIS CONDITION**

```
PatientXObservation O ON B.PatientId = O.PatientId
        AND O.ObservationId IN (1,2,4)
```

How to add this filter in the below SQL? I am not sure about how to add this here

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetDoctorOperationReportTest] 
( @IncludeVAT BIT = 0, @HasObservation BIT = 0 )
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON     

    SELECT 
        YEAR(StartTime) [Year]
      , MONTH(StartTime) [Month]
      , COUNT(BookingId) [BookingCount]
      , SUM(CASE 
          WHEN IsVAT = 1 AND @IncludeVAT = 1
          THEN (Price / 100) * 80
          ELSE Price
          END) AS TotalPrice
      , C.CategoryId
      , CategoryName
    FROM Category c
    LEFT JOIN Booking B ON C.CategoryId = B.CategoryId
    WHERE
      C.IncludeReport = 1
    GROUP BY YEAR(StartTime), MONTH(StartTime), C.CategoryId, CategoryName
    ORDER BY 1, 2, CategoryName
END
```

I have tried with TEMP table but the query is running **very very slow**. Other issue here is if @HasObservation is 0 i need to avoid this filter , but unfortunately it chooses observation=0 :(

```
SELECT B.BookingId
    ,B.StartTime
    ,B.IsVAT
    ,B.Price
    ,c.CategoryId
    ,c.CategoryName
    ,c.IncludeReport
    ,observation = (
        CASE 
            WHEN isnull(o.PatientId, 0) = 0
                THEN 0
            ELSE 1
            END
        )
INTO #Temp
FROM Category c
LEFT JOIN Booking B ON C.CategoryId = B.CategoryId
LEFT JOIN PatientXObservation O ON B.PatientId = O.PatientId
    AND O.ObservationId IN (1,2,4)



SELECT YEAR(StartTime) [Year]
    ,MONTH(StartTime) [Month]
    ,COUNT(BookingId) [BookingCount]
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN IsVAT = 1
                AND @IncludeVAT = 1
                THEN (Price / 100) * 80
            ELSE Price
            END) AS TotalPrice
    ,CategoryId
    ,CategoryName
FROM #Temp
WHERE IncludeReport = 1
    AND observation = @HasObservation
GROUP BY YEAR(StartTime)
    ,MONTH(StartTime)
    ,CategoryId
    ,CategoryName
ORDER BY 1
    ,2
    ,CategoryName
```

Comment: Think of a SELECT statement you could use to simply return all PatientId you're not interested in, as a set of keys. You can then use an outer join to make sure B.PatientId is not in that list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the IN clause to filter only if your @HasObservation parameter is non-zero:

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(StartTime) [Year]
  , MONTH(StartTime) [Month]
  , COUNT(BookingId) [BookingCount]
  , SUM(CASE 
      WHEN IsVAT = 1 AND @IncludeVAT = 1
      THEN (Price / 100) * 80
      ELSE Price
      END) AS TotalPrice
  , C.CategoryId
  , CategoryName
FROM Category c
LEFT JOIN Booking B ON C.CategoryId = B.CategoryId
WHERE
  C.IncludeReport = 1
  and (@HasObservation=0 
        or B.PatientID in 
            (select PatientID 
            from PatientXObservation O 
            where ObservationId IN (1,2,4))
        )
GROUP BY YEAR(StartTime), MONTH(StartTime), C.CategoryId, CategoryName
ORDER BY 1, 2, CategoryName
```

Comment: This practically had me running downstairs at 1am to fetch my notebook, but you beat me to it!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an `IF` statement like the following.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetDoctorOperationReportTest] 
  ( @IncludeVAT BIT = 0, @HasObservation BIT = 0 )
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON
 IF @HasObservation = 1 
  BEGIN
   SELECT 
       YEAR(StartTime) [Year]
     , MONTH(StartTime) [Month]
     , COUNT(BookingId) [BookingCount]
     , SUM(CASE 
         WHEN IsVAT = 1 AND @IncludeVAT = 1
         THEN (Price / 100) * 80
         ELSE Price
         END) AS TotalPrice
     , C.CategoryId
     , CategoryName
   FROM Category c
   LEFT JOIN Booking B ON C.CategoryId = B.CategoryId
   LEFT JOIN PatientXObservation O 
          ON B.PatientId = O.PatientId
         AND O.ObservationId IN (1,2,4)
   WHERE C.IncludeReport = 1
   GROUP BY YEAR(StartTime), MONTH(StartTime), C.CategoryId, CategoryName
   ORDER BY 1, 2, CategoryName
  END
 ELSE
  BEGIN
   SELECT 
       YEAR(StartTime) [Year]
     , MONTH(StartTime) [Month]
     , COUNT(BookingId) [BookingCount]
     , SUM(CASE 
         WHEN IsVAT = 1 AND @IncludeVAT = 1
         THEN (Price / 100) * 80
         ELSE Price
         END) AS TotalPrice
     , C.CategoryId
     , CategoryName
   FROM Category c
   LEFT JOIN Booking B ON C.CategoryId = B.CategoryId
   WHERE
     C.IncludeReport = 1
   GROUP BY YEAR(StartTime), MONTH(StartTime), C.CategoryId, CategoryName
   ORDER BY 1, 2, CategoryName
  END
END
```

Comment: I don't see where they're being filtered, and you might get duplicates now.

Comment: It's simply an IF/Else based on the BIT operator @HasObservation; It uses his same code, plus his join condition.  Not sure how that would return dups, unless his provided code would return dups to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

Your join should be:

```
LEFT JOIN PatientXObservation O 
          ON B.PatientId = O.PatientId
```

Then add the predicate

```
WHERE  (@HasObservation = 1 AND O.ObservationId IN (1,2,4)) OR (@HasObservation = 0 AND O.ObservationId < 0)
```

Comment: Total Rows currently 7233. After adding this condition and left join i am getting 83 if @HasObservation=1 which is correct. `But getting 8400 for @HasObservation=0 is wrong. I should get 7233 only`

Comment: I have made an edit. I've assumed O.ObservationId should never be less than 0. Provided that's the case, including a predicate for O.ObservationId<0 along with @HasObservation =0 will exclude any records from the observations table and prevent the extra records you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Change your WHERE to have the two versions of @HasObservation return what is needed.  If I understand your question, then if @HasObservation = 1 then there is a further filter.  The SQL would be as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetDoctorOperationReportTest] 
( @IncludeVAT BIT = 0, @HasObservation BIT = 0 )
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON     

SELECT 
    YEAR(StartTime) [Year]
  , MONTH(StartTime) [Month]
  , COUNT(BookingId) [BookingCount]
  , SUM(CASE 
      WHEN IsVAT = 1 AND @IncludeVAT = 1
      THEN (Price / 100) * 80
      ELSE Price
      END) AS TotalPrice
  , C.CategoryId
  , CategoryName
FROM Category c
LEFT JOIN Booking B ON C.CategoryId = B.CategoryId
LEFT JOIN PatientXObservation O 
    ON B.PatientId = O.PatientId
WHERE
  C.IncludeReport = 1
  and
  (
    (
        @HasObservation = 0         
    )
    or
    (
        @HasObservation = 1
        and O.ObservationId IN (1,2,4)
    )
)

GROUP BY YEAR(StartTime), MONTH(StartTime), C.CategoryId, CategoryName
ORDER BY 1, 2, CategoryName
END
```

Your @HasObservation = 0 could have a different filter if needed; you would just need to adjust the code to include some exclusionary logic.

Comment: Total Rows currently 7233. After adding this condition and left join i am getting 83 if @HasObservation=1 which is correct. `But getting 8400 for @HasObservation=0 is wrong. I should get 7233 only`

Comment: Try adding a conditional to the "@HasObservation = 0".  Look at the extra 1167 rows and see if there is a common variable, then exclude it.  For example, you can exclude if O.ObservationId is NULL or something.  

    (
    @HasObservation = 0
    and
    O.ObservationId is NULL
    )